# Directory listing sorted by size, but with opt*.* at the top

Tags: command-line, ms-dos

I wish to list in reverse size order the files in a certain directory.

This is easy: 
use `dir /o-s/b >dir.lis`.

However I want the files named opt*.* to always appear at the top regardless of file size.

Not sure how to do this.
I could do this is two steps, such as
`dir /o-s opt*.* >dir.lis`
and issue a second command to list the rest.

But how do I exclude opt*.* from the second listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I exclude `opt*.*` from the second listing?

You can use [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to achieve this:

```
dir /b /o-s *.* | findstr /bivr /c:"opt*.*"
```

Where:

- `/b` Match pattern if at the Beginning of a line.
- `/i` Case-insensitive search
- `/v` Print only lines that do NOT contain a match
- `/r` Use string as a regular expression
- `/c"string"` Use string as a literal search string (may include spaces)

So putting the following two commands together will do what you want (list the `opt*.*` files first)

```
rem get opt*.* files
dir /b /o-s opt*.* > dir.lis
rem get the rest of the files excluding opt*.*
dir /b /o-s *.* | findstr /bivr /c:"opt*.*" >> dir.lis
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.

Comment: Thanks.  It removes all the opt*.* files, but also all the loop*.* files too.  Why would it be removing these too?

Comment: I've updated the answer to lock the regexp to the beginning of the line (using the `findstr` option `/b`), which fixes this problem.

Comment: Intrigued as to why did the first one not work.  How did it match loop to opt* ?

Comment: @dacfer No idea without seeing a list of all your opt and loop filenames.

Comment: D:\>type x.x
optim02.log
optim02a.log
optim01.log
loop_df.log
loop_gr.log
loop_dr.log
loop_hb.log
loop_fb.log
loop_bb.log

D:\>findstr /ivr /c:"opt*.*" <x.x

D:\>

Comment: Sorry line spacing not working in these comments, hope you can make sense - I listed the files in x.x and then issued the findstr command reading from x.x.  Nothing was matched.

Comment: no all separate lines

Comment: D:\>type x.x<eol>
optim02.log<eol>
optim02a.log<eol>
optim01.log<eol>
loop_df.log<eol>
loop_gr.log<eol>
loop_dr.log<eol>
loop_hb.log<eol>
loop_fb.log<eol>
loop_bb.log<eol>
<eol>
D:\>findstr /ivr /c:"opt*.*" <x.x<eol>
<eol>
D:\><eol>
replace all <eol> with real end-of-line

Comment: @dacfer *shrug*. Don't know why.